# Are scheduled reports sent to subscribed users if no records are available?

Tags: reporting, administration

In case no records are available in for the scheduled report, will the subscribed user get an email with an empty report? or no email is sent?

We are using scheduled monthly reports and we need the report to be sent even if no data is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The report is sent even when no records are returned. It's interesting that you consider this the desired behavior. A lot of users think different, [see this idea at success.salesforce.com](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873000000075I4AAI).

Comment: Hi Fred, it's actually a customer request rather than my call